# In-app Purchasing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to get this whole in-app purchasing to work, but I have encountered some problems. So I am able to "buy" the features with my test user account, but I want to test again and again. So I made a delete method that gets rid of the keychain that is generated and quit the app, then build it again and it is back to the "free" state, where I once again try to buy the app, but this time it gives me "you've already purchased this item, tap OK to download it again" so I tap ok, but this time nothing happens and no features get unlock, wtf?

code:

```
 -(void)deleteKeyChain:(id)sender {

NSError *error = nil;
NSLog(@"delete!!!!");
[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:@"someUser" andServiceName:kStoredData            error:&error];

 }

-(void)doFeature:(id)sender {
[newPlayer pause];
if ([self IAPItemPurchased]) {

    // do the feature 2!
   //       featureLabel.text = @"Feature: 2";

} else {
    // not purchased so show a view to prompt for purchase
    askToPurchase = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle:@"All Features"
                     message:@"Tap refresh anytime to read latest 5 emails. To read all      emails with no ads and to continue reading in the background, please purchase the full version of this app."
                     delegate:self
                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                     otherButtonTitles:@"OK",@"Later on", nil];
    askToPurchase.delegate = self;
    [askToPurchase show];
    [askToPurchase release];
     }
   }


   #pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

  -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions     {
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

            // show wait view here
         //        statusLabel.text = @"Processing...";
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view and unlock feature 2
    //        statusLabel.text = @"Done!";
            UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Complete"
                                message:@"You now have the full version of Emails Aloud!!"
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [tmp show];
            [tmp release];


            NSError *error = nil;
            [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:@"someUser" andPassword:@"pass"   forServiceName:kStoredData updateExisting:YES error:&error];

            // apply purchase action  - hide lock overlay and
         //   [feature2Btn setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            // do other thing to enable the features

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view here
            //    statusLabel.text = @"";
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled=%d",transaction.error.code);
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view here
         //   statusLabel.text = @"Purchase Error!";
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
      }
    }






-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse   *)response
 {

   // remove wait view here
   // statusLabel.text = @"";

SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];

if (count>0) {
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment    paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.myapp.shit"];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];


} else {
    UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                        message:@"No products to purchase"
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [tmp show];
    [tmp release];
}


 }

  -(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
 {
[request release];
 }

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (alertView==askToPurchase) {
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        // user tapped YES, but we need to check if IAP is enabled or not.
        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {

            SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.myapp.shit"]];

            request.delegate = self;
            [request start];


        } else {
            UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Prohibited"
                                message:@"Parental Control is enabled, cannot make a  purchase!"
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [tmp show];
            [tmp release];
           }
       }
    }

}
```

note:The someUser/pass is not a username/password of anybody. It is just a text that I chose to register the users in app purchase into their device.

Answer (score 1):

IF you already purchased the application with the user/password from the iTunes Connect user, you need to look for `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` and not `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`.

`SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` only happens once per user for a non-consumable product.  Try creating many more test users on iTunes Connect.

Comment: yeah, i have, and it actually works everytime i make a new test user, but none get to the point where i can delete the keychain and restart the app and then purchase again

Comment: Why are you making them repurchase every time the turn on/restart the app?

Comment: well before i turn off the app i tap a button that is targeted to the "deleteKeyChain" method, i guess i dont have to restart the app, i have done it where i dont, but same behavior

Comment: "SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased only happens once per user for a non-consumable product. Try creating many more test users on iTunes Connect." is this true even if you get rid of keychain?

Comment: ok yeah i moved    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];  to the case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored: and now i get the features back, but still with the "you already purchased this app, tap ok to download again," is that always going to show up, even if you delete the the keychain? i am using a non-consumable. O and if i had 15 rep points i would upvote this answer